# White-space not working

Tags: html, css

I have create a `div` with css below:

```
.inner-overlay {
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1301;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 3px solid rgba(56, 93, 138, 1.0);
    display: none;
}
```

And the `div` included the form with css:

```
.reportTable {
    width: 460px;
    margin: auto;
}
.reportTable tr td:nth-child(1) {
   width: 20px;
}
.reportTable tr td:nth-child(2) {
   width: 400px;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

For the `div` and the `form`:

```
<div class="inner-overlay" style="display: block;">
    <form class="reportForm">
    <table class="reportTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Please Choose A Reason From Below:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="reportID" value="1"></td>
        <td>There is/are course work content or answer.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="reportID" value="2"></td>
        <td>The content is not related to academic.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="reportID" value="3"></td>
        <td>There is/are suspicious file uploaded.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="reportID" value="4"></td>
        <td>asdasdasdasd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="reportID" value="5"></td>
                    <td>asdasfasfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><span id="submitReport" onclick="javascript: submitReport(&quot;notes&quot;, &quot;29&quot;)">Submit</span> <span id="cancelReport" onclick="javascript: $(&quot;.overlay&quot;).hide(); $(&quot;.inner-overlay&quot;).hide();">Cancel</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
    </form>
</div>
```

The image below is the design of my table. But the `white-space` is not working as it should be.

[image: Overflow not working]

Is there anything I missed out?

EDIT :

1. Added the HTML code.
2. Uploaded to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnonyNewbie/saygP/).

Comment: Post your HTML. And a jsFiddle would help.

Comment: can i look at your html file which uses this css??

Comment: @j08691, thanks for reminding me. I have added the HTML code and uploaded to jsFiddle as well.

Comment: All those kinds of `&quot;` are generated by my php function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the `word-break:break-all;` rule to your cell it should work:

```
.reportTable tr td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 400px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break:break-all;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/saygP/1/)**

Comment: Can I know why the `white-space` is not enough to do the work?

Comment: Think of the white-space rule as the opposite of the word-break rule. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space